# BarCode Issue While Printing in HTML format

Tags: c#, html, pdf, printing, barcode

We have an online transport application which prints tickets in PDF format which includes barcode for scanning while travelling.Currently we have to change printing format from PDF to HTML.While doing that Barcode is not getting printed.So,is it possible to have Barcode printed in HTML format?More Info related to this would be grateful...

Comment: a list with all items float:left and with a specific witdh and use the background color to make it a barcode :)

Comment: I think you'd struggle to get this spot on using css. Different browsers and resolutions will play a nightmare with your spacing.

Comment: ok,i would check that..changing css..

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you pregenerate the barcode as an image and get it to the page? [Here](http://barcoderender.codeplex.com/) is a simple opensource library that could do just that. Example is included.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an HTML representation of your barcode, just remember: The way a page is showed depends on the styles you apply to it, and the way the client interprets it (That's wy I.E. is a pain in the...).

A barcode has dimension restrictions to be interpreted. That would make your styling a mess.

Besides, when printing a webpage, the client (Internet Explorer, Mozilla, Chrome, Safari etc.) could have been configured by the user to save ink or improve legibility, so the barcode might not get printed the best.

I'm with [t3hn00b](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12156376/2661480). The easiest would be to generate the barcode in server as a jpg or png that is inserted in your html. That way you keep the dimensions and your barcode is less prone to errors when printing.